# Storyboard上のNavigationBarにBar Button Itemを置く

Tags: xcode, storyboard, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

`NavigationController`から別の`ViewController`にcontrolキー + クリックで引っ張ってshowを選択すると、`ViewController`に`NavigationBar`が表示されると思うんですが、この`NavigationBar`に`Storyboard`上で`Bar Button Item`を追加することはできないのでしょうか？プログラムで配置するしかないのでしょうか？
ということは、このshowを選択した時に表示される`NavigationBar`は、`ViewController`にEmbed in → Navigation Controller としたとき表示される`NavigationBar`とは少し違いがあるのでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。
すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず、`Navigation Item`を、`Navigation Bar`にドロップして、つぎに`Bar Button Item`をドロップしましょう。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Document Outlineで、こういうヒエラルキーになっているのを確認してください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

> Embed in → Navigation Controller としたとき表示されるNavigationBarとは少し違いがあるのでしょうか？

正直言わせてもらうと、`Navigation Controller`から、ダイレクトに`View Controller`に、`Show`の`Segue`を引っ張るケース（そのような必然性）を想像できないので、なんともお答えいたしかねます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。Navigation Item、Navigation Bar、Bar Button Itemの順でドロップすると実現したいことができました。Navigation Controllerから、ダイレクトにView Controllerに、ShowのSegueを引っ張るケースはないのですね。参考にさせていただきます。ありがとうございました。